# Getting selected value of UIAutomation Combo Box

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ui-automation

I'm trying to get a combo box's selected value using UIAutomation. So far my code is as follows:

```
var cbx = tree.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "desktopCbx"));
var value = cbx.Current.Name;
```

It does not give me the right value. How can I get the right one?

Comment: Does UISpy show the text in cbx.Current.Name ?

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox [AutomationElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the [ValuePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.valuepattern(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use this pattern to set or get the selected value of the ComboBox.

I use these methods in my framework to set and get the value from an AutomationElement that is supporting the ValuePattern:

```
public static string Element_GetValue(AutomationElement control)
{
    string value = null;

    object patternProvider;
    if (control.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out patternProvider))
    {
        ValuePattern valuePatternProvider = patternProvider as ValuePattern;
        value = valuePatternProvider.Current.Value;
    }

    return value;
}

public static bool Element_SetValue(AutomationElement control, string value)
{
    object patternProvider;
    if (control.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out patternProvider))
    {
        ValuePattern valuePatternProvider = patternProvider as ValuePattern;
        valuePatternProvider.SetValue(value);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In your scenario you can use the `Element_GetValue()` method like this:

```
var cbx = tree.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "desktopCbx"));
var value = Element_GetValue(cbx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Combobox is a composite control containing of an edit control, a button (for dropdown) and a list.
The selected item text is usually a property of the edit control child of the combobox.

UI Spy should clear this up pretty fast.